# MySQL join to see if record exists in other table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `accommodations` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `accommodations_exclude` (
  `id_accommodation` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_course` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_course` (`id_course`,`id_accommodation`)
)
```

In the accommodations table there are 4 records, in the accommodations_exclude there are many more. Now I would like to have a query that always give me all records from the accommodations table, and joined as extra field to see if the accommodation also exists in the accommodations_exclude table.

For example; in the accommodations_exclude there is one row with id_accommodation = 2, id_course = 16.

I want to have a resultset that shows me the following:

```
accommodation.id, accommodation.name, accommodation_exclude.id_accommodation, accommodation_exclude.id_course

1,'acco 1',null,null
2,'acco 2',2,16
3,'acco 3',null,null
4,'acco 4',null,null
```

The query I have right now is this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM accommodations a
LEFT JOIN accommodations_exclude ae ON a.id = ae.id_accommodation 
WHERE ae.id_course = 16
```

but this gives me only the resultset

```
2,'acco 2',2,16
```

and not the accommodations that should have null values

any idea on what i do wrong here ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move the `ae.id_course = 16` clause from `WHERE` to your `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM accommodations a
LEFT JOIN accommodations_exclude ae ON
    a.id = ae.id_accommodation
    AND ae.id_course = 16
```

You should think of  `WHERE` as a filter on the final resultset, anything to do with linking tables should be conditions in your `JOIN`s.

Your original `WHERE ae.id_course = 16` was filtering out the NULL ae.id_course rows from the resultset.

Comment: thanks, this did the trick! I indeed didn't realize I can put this already in the JOIN conditions

Answer (score 1):

Make the `accommodations_exclude` table the left table, or use `RIGHT JOIN` instead like so:

```
SELECT
 a.id, 
 a.name, 
 ae.id_accommodation, 
  ae.id_course
FROM accommodations a
RIGHT JOIN accommodations_exclude ae ON a.id = ae.id_accommodation;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61022/4)

This will give you:

```
| ID |   NAME | ID_ACCOMMODATION | ID_COURSE |
----------------------------------------------
|  1 | acco 1 |           (null) |    (null) |
|  2 | acco 2 |                2 |        16 |
|  3 | acco 3 |           (null) |    (null) |
|  4 | acco 4 |           (null) |    (null) |
```

**Note that:** For the sample data you posted, the `WHERE ae.id_course = 16` will return only one row, that had `ae.id_course = 16`.

Comment: this gives me all the results from the accommodations_exclude table, it's not what I was looking for. The solution from Ross works perfectly !

Comment: It's not good solution, because if there is not record in `accommodations_exclude table, then return just record #2, see here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8ed4/6/0

Answer (score 0):

It wont give you any more based on your condition

```
WHERE ae.id_course = 16
```

It is giving you the proper resultset. Remove that and it will list all of them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right, it will list all of them, so also the accommomdation_exclude rows that have a different id_course than 16. It is not what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ACCOMMODATION.ID, ACCOMMODATION.NAME,
       ACCOMMODATION_EXCLUDE.ID_ACCOMMODATION,
       ACCOMMODATION_EXCLUDE.ID_COURSE
  FROM ACCOMMODATION, ACCOMMODATION_EXCLUDE
 WHERE ACCOMMODATION.ID = ACCOMMODATION_EXCLUDE.ID_ACCOMMODATION(+)
       AND ACCOMMODATION_EXCLUDE.ID_COURSE = 16
```

Comment: thanks, but this query gives me an error. Ross's solution works though :)

Answer (score 0):

[The answer from "Ross McNab"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14254713/1407491) is the best, but if you don't have use condition in `JOIN` you can use this sample code:

```
SELECT *
FROM accommodations a
LEFT JOIN accommodations_exclude ae ON a.id = ae.id_accommodation 
WHERE ae.id_course = 16 OR ae.id_course IS NULL
```